# The Mouse and touchpad section within display settings flickers very fast and is not responding in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: gnome, display-settings

The Mouse and touchpad section within display settings flickers very fast and is not responding in Ubuntu 19.10:

[image]

The entire screen remains stuck when such fast flickering is occurring. This occurs whenever I land up into this section (mouse and touchpad section) alone. All other parts are working fine. I will have to kill the process or press multiple times the cross button to abort the flickering.

Any ideas on how this could be corrected?

Comment: Possibly [askubuntu.com/questions/1215796](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215796)

Comment: Got the solution from the above link shared.... Any ideas on the logic behind the glitch.